# How to extract specific audio track (track 2) from mp4 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am working on a mp4 file (36017P.mp4) in which I want to extract `Track 2 -[English]` using ffmpeg.

[image]

I tried with the following command on terminal but it seems to extract `Track 1 - [English]`:

```
ffmpeg -i 36017P.mp4 filename.mp3
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the ffmpeg command above so that it extract `Track 2 -[English]` from mp4 file.

Comment: Update with... What is the output of just using `ffmpeg -i 36017P.mp4`? or even try `ffprobe -i 36017P.mp4`? Let's see what tracks FFmpeg will detect...

Answer (score 5):

The `-map` option will do what you want.  Below in `-map 0:a:1` the `0` refers to the first (and only) input file. `a` refers to the audio channels and the next number - `1` here - selects a specific audio stream, starting from 0:

```
ffmpeg -i 36017P.mp4 -map 0:a:0 filename1.mp3
ffmpeg -i 36017P.mp4 -map 0:a:1 filename2.mp3
ffmpeg -i 36017P.mp4 -map 0:a:2 filename3.mp3
ffmpeg -i 36017P.mp4 -map 0:a:3 filename4.mp3
```

For further details, see section [5.11 Advanced options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) in the ffmpeg docs.